# REST API Key expires roughly after an hour

Tags: authentication, here-api, here-maps-rest

Each time I create a REST API Key it shows as expired after approx 1 hr.

This keeps happening although I have verified my account email.

Comment: Which API are you using: can you add the http request and the response code and body you get? How do you create the API Key?

Comment: You should contact the support of the service you are using. We will unlikely be able to help you.

Comment: Could you confirm if you are using a Here Freemium account?
Generally, when the account is not activated you might see a yellow notice, under the Project Details section. The notice explains that the account needs to be activated until then the API key is valid for 1 hr. Please verify and confirm?